# Equals in EL: what if the first operand is null?

Tags: el

If I have an `EL` expression like this one:

```
#{a == b}
```

what happens if `a` is `null`? There is some difference between different versions of EL?

Where can I found an official specs that explain that?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? What happens when you try it yourself?

Comment: I suspect this is about whether an NPE is thrown or not? Could you simply test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From official EL specs 2.1 section 1.8.2](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf#page=26&zoom=100,88,670):

> If A is null or B is null return false

There are special cases for `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger`. I don't know for the other specs.

Comment: I fixed your link. It contained an authentication token that was not valid for other users.

Comment: Why are there special cases for certain types? What are these special cases? Does the type matter for `null`?